# How do I obtain the state of a random number generator in c#?

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to figure out what values are causing some bad output.  It's a low-probability scenario so I would like to simply log all the inputs to the generator until I find a bad seed.  Unfortunately, that means recording the state of the random generator and I see no way to get at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to record the state of the generator at any given point (which I don't think is possible)? As long as you record the seed, and the number of times it was called (you may need to create a class to wrap the random generator), it should be enough to reproduce the scenario, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `System.Random` and override its methods as all of them are virtual. You could then log the results returned from each call.